# Select maximum element in numpy column and also get it's row

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to do the following, given an numpy array 'A', I need to get the maximum element (in absolute value) of each column and also get the row of this element (duplicate values do not matter).

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
    [[1, 1, 1],
     [2, 1, 3],
     [3, 1, 6]], dtype=float)
```

My naive solution so far is the following:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    max_elm_col = A[0,i]
    max_elm_row = 0
    for index, el in enumerate(A[0:, i]):
        if abs(el) > max_elm_col:
            max_elm_col = el
            max_elm_row = index

    print(max_elm_col, max_elm_row)
```

Which outputs:

```
3.0 2
1.0 0
6.0 2
```

While this indeed solves my problem, but could look more (num)Pythonic. So I tried to rework it like this:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    # cool way
    max_elm_col = max(A[0:,i], key = abs)
    print(max_elm_col)
```

Which outputs:

```
3.0
1.0
6.0
```

After checking the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax), the same can be done with **np.amax**, but it won't let me use a **key = abs**.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    max_elm_col = np.amax(A[0:,i], axis=0)
    print(max_elm_col)
```

Since I'm unfamiliar with numpy I would like any hints on performing this task in a more numpyish way.

Comment: [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to calc the `abs` values in a stacked array like:

#### Code:

```
maxs = np.vstack([A, np.abs(A)]).argmax(axis=0) % A.shape[0]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
    [[1,  1, 1],
     [2, -2, 3],
     [2,  1, 3],
     [3,  1, 6]], dtype=float)


maxs = np.vstack([A, np.abs(A)]).argmax(axis=0) % A.shape[0]
print(maxs)
print(A[maxs, np.arange(A.shape[1])])
```

#### Results:

```
[3 1 3]
[ 3. -2.  6.]
```